# Tastypie - Accessing Field Data Through ForeignKey Field

Tags: python, django, api, tastypie

I have a Tastypie resource (TaskImagesResource) which needs to override the obj_get_list function to return the correct data when a request is made to the API. I need to access properties of another resource (TaskResource, which has a OneToOne relationship with TaskImagesResource) in order to do this. I can get an instance of the Task resource using get_related_resource() but I don't know how to get data out of the object. Here is my code now:

```
class TaskResource(ModelResource):
    target = fields.OneToOneField(TargetResource, 'target', full=True)
    activity = fields.ForeignKey(ActivityResource, 'activity')
    time = fields.OneToOneField(TaskEventTimeResource, 'time', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Task.objects.all()
        filtering = {
            'id' : ALL,
            'activity' : ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
     }

class TaskImagesResource(Resource):
    task = fields.ForeignKey(TaskResource, 'task', full=True)
    camera = fields.CharField()

    def obj_get_list(self, request, **kwargs):
        task_resource = self.task.get_related_resource(self)
        task = Task.objects.get(id=task_resource.id)
        image_list = task.sorted_imageinstances(self.camera)
```

But I'm getting the error "int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'CharField'" because task_resource.id is a CharField object and not the data itself. How can I access the actual Field data?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
task = Task.objects.get(id=int(task_resource.id))
```

Comment: The CharField couldn't be cast to an integer.

Comment: Looks like there's something wrong with `task_resource = self.task.get_related_resource(self)` then. Try to print/log the output of `task_resource` to debug.